# How to apply materials to specific faces only?

Tags: materials

I imported an object with many faces and materials, but I only want some materials to apply to certain faces, how could I do this? When I add the material, it adds it to the entire thing, how do I do it for one face?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy to do; first, go into *Edit Mode*, by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and select the faces on which you want the material to apply.

Then, go to the *Properties* panel, and in the *Material* tab, with the material you want selected on the list above, press *Assign*.

[image]

Notice that you can also select/deselect the faces corresponding to a material, by pressing the respective button.

Comment: If I change the material then all faces, not only the selected ones gets that material.

Comment: @AndersLindén Are you sure you did everything correctly? And if so, can you provide a simple  .blend file showing the problem?

Comment: Oh, I thought the dropdown contained the materials that I can choose in the mesh, but the list contains those. The dropdowns contains materials for the whole file.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit confusing. Those in the list are the ones linked to your object, and those in the dropdown are all the material currently present (they may or may not be linked to any object). Anyway, does it work now?

Comment: Yes, it is working!